# Несколько клиентов в Soket server python

Tags: python

Как сделать что-бы могло подключиться несколько клиентов к soket серверу на python

Код сервера:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
c, addr = sock.accept()

print ('connected:', addr)
while 1==1:
       while True:
               data = c.recv(1024)
               if not data:
                       break
               if data == b'help':
                       c.send(b'Server>>Help is out of index')
               else:
                       c.send(b'Server>>Command is wrong')
               #c.send(data.upper())
               print(data)
c.close()
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
i = 1
while i == 1:
    com = input('Enter command:')
    if len(com) <= 0:
        print('Please enter command!')
    else:
        sock.send(bytearray(com,'ascii'))
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print (data.decode('utf-8'))
sock.close()
```

Comment: Или отправлять каждого подключившегося клиента в отдельный поток, или использовать select, или взять asyncio (или аналог)

Comment: andreymal то есть асинхронный tcp-сервер?